# Changing occurrences of one pattern to another

Tags: ubuntu, sed, rename, replace

`grep -R \"\/web *`
gives me some occurrences which i want to change to
`\"\$\/web`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command-line: `sed -i 's/"\/web/"$\/web/g' FILENAME`, or omit `-i` and `FILENAME` if piping input.

Take care when doing it though - it might be a good idea to run without `-i` first, and then with it if you are sure that the results are exactly what you want.

For multiple files: `find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/"\/web/"$\/web/g' {} \;`

Comment: it is giving me an error sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed

```
sed -r 's|"(/web)|"$\1|g' *
```

If your satisfied with the output, change `sed -r` to `sed -ri` to do an in-place edit

Answer (score 0):

In vim:

```
:set hidden
:args *
:argdo %s/"web/"$web/g
:wqa
```

Comment: but i want to do this over a large number of files distribute in a folder hierarchy

Comment: Then replace `args *` with `args **/*`. to whomever downvoted: why? Doesn't that work too?